# How to define a stop-hook for lldb in .lldbinit?

Tags: lldb

I would like to define the following stop hook:

```
target stop-hook add --one-liner "frame variable"
```

in my .lldbinit so that frame variables are shown by default on every stop.
While entering this in lldb after start works but it has no effect being in my .lldbinit. I do not want to enter it every time after lldb starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known bug.  There are a couple of "target specific" things, breakpoints being the other crucial one, that you can't set without a target to set them into.

You can work around this either by putting it in the .lldbinit file in the directory you are in when you launch lldb, or you can do something hacky like:

```
lldb -o 'target stop-hook add --one-liner "frame variable"' executable-name
```

That will source in the stop hook command after the executable, so we'll have a target to work with.  You could even make this a shell alias to make life easier.

Comment: Based on your idea I aliased lldb to 'lldb -s ~/.someprefix.lldbinit' and removed the original lldbinit. Works. Thanks!

Comment: Many years later in case someone else finds this, enable the loading of local .lldbinit files in your ~/.lldbinit and then create your <project>/,lldbinit with the target set.  "settings set target.load-cwd-lldbinit true".

Answer (score 1):

Also... many years later.  The answer above is not relevant if you are using an lldb that's from 2016 or later.

lldb added support for setting breakpoints and stop-hooks in the ~/.lldbinit around that time.  So this workaround should no longer be necessary.

stop-hooks and breakpoints from the ~/.lldbinit will be set in a "Dummy Target" and then copied into any new target as they get created.  There is also -D option to `break delete` that will delete breakpoints from the dummy target, so they won't get copied into any new targets within the same session.